# Testing Array membership in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'd like to test whether or not an array contains a given object.

I suppose I could accomplish this with

```
some_array.index(object).should be_a_kind_of(Integer)
```

or

```
some_array.index(object).should_not be_nil
```

or

```
some_array.include?(object).should be_true
```

However, I'm hoping there's a more elegant way to express this, something like

```
some_array.should include(object)
```

but, you know, valid code. Is there?

Comment: What's wrong with `some_array.should include(object)` ? Are you getting some kind of error ? There is a [matcher for include](http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.9/classes/Spec/Matchers.html#M000436).

Comment: Well, I could have sworn that it was giving me some kind of error before. Trying again, it seems to work perfectly. I guess I answered my own question without knowing it! Thanks.